# VK API. Работа с сообщениями

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как проверить сообщение на наличие attachments с помощью VK API на Python?

Comment: А как у вас уже получилось?

Comment: Немного не понял вопроса, но у меня не получается это сделать, вот я и спрашиваю: как?

Comment: Получить сообщение согласно документации https://vk.com/dev и посмотреть на ответ сервера?

Comment: @andreymal как средствами Python проверить, содержит ли ответ поле attachment или нет? Python выдает ошибку если его нет, а к нему обращаются

Comment: @korzh а это уже ВК не касается и самые основы питона, `if 'attachments' in где_там_надо_проверить`

Comment: @andreymal большое спасибо. Помогли

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял вопрос, что имелось ввиду. Если вам дан id сообщения, то можно использовать метод [messages.getById](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getById). Пример (используя библиотеку vk_api):

```
id = 12345
if vk.method("messages.getById",{"message_ids":id})["items"][0]["attachments"] is not []:
    print("медиавложения есть")
else:
    print("медиавложений нет")
```

Comment: Попробуйте ради интереса сделать `[] is not []`